# Sending html canvas binary data to Google Photos API

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm trying to upload an image from canvas to Google Photos:

**Step 1: [Upload binary image data](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media#upload-process)**

```
POST https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Authorization: Bearer OAuth2_TOKEN
X-Goog-Upload-File-Name: FILENAME
MEDIA_BINARY_DATA
```

My `MEDIA_BINARY_DATA` is

```
function get_binary_data_from_canvas(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-upload");
  return canvas.toDataURL(); // <- my binary data
}
```

I get an **uploadToken**

**Step 2: [Create Media Item](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media#creating-media-item)**

I send a valid request with the **uploadToken** I obtained in the previous step.

In the response I get:

```
 "NOT_IMAGE: There was an error while trying to create this media item"
```

**So what is the right way to generate the binary data from a HTML canvas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`canvas.toBlob` will probably help you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob